# Python 3.5: multiple client - server chat

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, python-3.x

At the moment I can send messages to and from clients using the server as a middleman.

However I cannot get the messages that are received by each client to be printed out before a user inputs something. I have come across threading however I am very inexperienced with it.

Server code:

```
import socket, _thread

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 

host = socket.gethostname()                           
port = 9999
serversocket.bind((host, port))                                  

serversocket.listen(5)

def send_c2(clientsocket1, clientsocket2):
    while True:
        msg1 = clientsocket1.recv(1024)
        msg1 = msg1.decode('ascii')
        clientsocket2.send(msg1.encode('ascii'))

def send_c1(clientsocket1, clientsocket2):
    while True:
        msg2 = clientsocket2.recv(1024)
        msg2 = msg2.decode('ascii')
        clientsocket1.send(msg2.encode('ascii'))

while True:
    clientsocket1,addr = serversocket.accept()          
    print("Got a connection from %s" % str(addr))
    clientsocket2,addr = serversocket.accept()
    print("Got a connection from %s" % str(addr))

    try:
        _thread.start_new_thread(send_c2, (clientsocket1, clientsocket2))
        _thread.start_new_thread(send_c1, (clientsocket1, clientsocket2))
    except:
        print("Thread failed")
```

Client code:

```
import socket, _thread

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 

host = socket.gethostname()                           
port = 9999
s.connect((host, port))                               

def send_msg(r, s):
    while True:
        msg = input("> ")
        s.send(msg.encode('ascii'))

def rec_msg(r, s):
    while True:
        tm = s.recv(1024)
        print(tm.decode('ascii'))

try:
    _thread.start_new_thread(send_msg, ("Thread 1", s))
    _thread.start_new_thread(rec_msg, ("Thread 2", s))
except:
    print("Thread failed")
```

Is there a way round this?